# How to make javac to ignore "unmappable character for encoding UTF-8" error (offending char is in comments)

Tags: encoding, utf-8, javac

I am compiling some legacy java code using plain javac.  The OS is linux and JDK level is:
java version "1.8.0_361"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 8.0.8.0 - pxa6480sr8-20230314_01(SR8))
I am getting errors like:
RpcApiUsingRPC.java:11121: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
* Write�0x64 to the command register on both RPCs to set the LEDs flashing.
I have seen this before but they used to be warnings.  But now it's errors and the classes are not compiled.
I am not in position to change all the source code, so I am wondering if there is a way to tell javac to ignore these. The offending characters are in comments.
Any tip is appreciated.

The build machine system default encoding is UTF-8.
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
I think javac should know these are comments and ignore the non utf-8 chars.

Comment: You don't need to "change" the source code, you just need to encode it properly. What *are* you able to do on the build machine?

Comment: When I said "I could not change ...", I meant I couldn't change code or the encoding of the files.  I looked at the encoding of a couple files and saw the encoding was Cp1252 (default of eclipse).  I set -encoding CP1252 on javac, that got rid of some errors but others still remain even the files had Cp1252 encoding.  Again, the bad chars are in comment lines which were ignored by older java compilers.  These is a large number of legacy java files so changing all of them is not practical.

Comment: Bad characters can be detected programmatically so you can change them with a script, regardless of the number of files